# Summing up property values using LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

I've a List of custom objects called Product: List

```
class Product
{
    string Key1 {get; set;}
    string Key2 {get; set;}
    int Count1 {get; set;}
    int Count2 {get; set;}
}
```

I'm combining multiple Product lists and I need to create a new list which will have sum values for each of the Count properties.
For e.g.

```
List 1:
"Key1", "Key2", 1, 2
"Key2", "Key3", 3, 4

List 2:
"Key1", "Key2", 5, 6
"Key2", "Key3", 7, 8
```

So my new List should be:

```
New List:
"Key1", "Key2", 6, 8
"Key2", "Key3", 10, 12
```

Can someone help me on this please?

Thanks.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `List 1: K1, K2, 1, 2 K2, K3, 3, 4`? Are they variables or literals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
var list1 = new List<Product>()
   {
      new Product(){Key1 = "Key1", Key2 ="Key2", Count1 = 1, Count2 = 2},
      new Product(){Key1 = "Key2", Key2 ="Key3", Count1 = 1, Count2 = 2}
   };

var list2 = new List<Product>()
   {
      new Product(){Key1 = "Key1", Key2 ="Key2", Count1 = 6, Count2 = 8},
      new Product(){Key1 = "Key2", Key2 ="Key3", Count1 = 10, Count2 = 12}
   };

var result = list1.Concat(list2)
                  .GroupBy(x => new {x.Key1,x.Key2})
                  .Select(x => new
                     {
                        x.Key.Key1,
                        x.Key.Key2,
                        SumCount1 = x.Sum(y => y.Count1),
                        SumCount2 = x.Sum(y => y.Count2)
                     }).ToList();
```

**Output**

[**Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uz7iRh)

```
Key1, Key2, 7, 10
Key2, Key3, 11, 14
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[List.AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Adds the elements of the specified collection to the end of the
>   List.

[Enumerable.GroupBy Method (IEnumerable, Func, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Groups the elements of a sequence according to a specified key
>   selector function and projects the elements for each group by using a
>   specified function.

[Enumerable.Concat Method (IEnumerable, IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Concatenates two sequences.

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<Product> lst1 = new List<Product>();
 List<Product> lst2 = new List<Product>();

 lst1.Add(new Product() {Key1 = "K1",Key2 ="K2", Count1 =1, Count2=2 });
 lst1.Add(new Product() { Key1 = "K2", Key2 = "K3", Count1 = 3, Count2 = 4 });

 lst2.Add(new Product() { Key1 = "K1", Key2 = "K2", Count1 = 5, Count2 = 6});
 lst2.Add(new Product() { Key1 = "K2", Key2 = "K3", Count1 = 7, Count2 = 8 });
// Way 1
 var l = lst1.Join(lst2, l1 => l1.Key1, l2 => l2.Key1, 
                (lt1, lt2) => new Product { Key1 = lt1.Key1, Key2 = lt1.Key2, Count1 = lt1.Count1 + lt2.Count1, Count2 = lt1.Count2 + lt2.Count2 } ).ToList() ;

// Way 2
var result = lst1.Join(lst2, x => new { x.Key1, x.Key2 },
                 y => new { y.Key1, y.Key2 }, (x, y) => 
                 new Product { Key1 = x.Key1, Key2 = x.Key2, Count1 = x.Count1 + y.Count1, Count2 = x.Count2 + y.Count2 }).ToList();
```